# Diferencia de días entre dos fechas

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

Tengo una tabla en la cual tengo dos campos llamados created_at y updated_at en una tabla llamada processes, lo que quiero hacer es comparar cuantos dias hay entre esos dos campos

Estoy utilizando laravel 6

controlador

```
$processes = Process::findOrFail(Crypt::decrypt(base64_decode($id)));
return view('clientes.show', compact('processes', 'histories', 'diligences', 'services', 'iva', 'dias'));
```

Consulta

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,created_at, updated_at) AS days FROM processes 
WHERE id = 1
```

Comment: aun no he intentado nada ya que no se como hacerlo

Comment: Lo único que he tratado es una consulta en mysql con datediff pero no se si te sirva

Comment: ya puse la consulta

Comment: pero podes poner los nombres de los campos en el sql.. cual seria el problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ya pude, puse esto en mi modelo y lo llamo en la vista blade

```
public function dias(){
        $fecha1 = date_create($this->created_at);
        $fecha2 = date_create($this->canceled_at);
        $dias = date_diff($fecha1, $fecha2)->format('%R%a');
        return $dias;
    }
```

blade

```
{{ $processes->dias() + 0 }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el método `diffInDays` que ya provee Carbon en Laravel.

Deberías:

- Tener tu modelo creado
- Obtener la fecha antigua y asignarla en una variable
- Obtener la fecha reciente y asignarla en una variable
- El resultado en días lo almacenas en una tercer variable donde como argumento del método antes citado pasas la fecha mas reciente.

**Ejemplo**

```
$fechaAntigua  = Modelo::first()->created_at;
$fechaReciente = Modelo::first()->updated_at;

$cantidadDias = $fechaAntigua->diffInDays($fechaReciente);
```

**EDICIÓN**

Agrego un ejemplo de uso del método `diffInDays()` desde *Tinker*

```
>>> $fechaAntigua = App\User::first()->created_at;

    => Illuminate\Support\Carbon @989686800 {#3113
         date: 2020-05-01 18:37:21.0 America/Mexico_City (-05:00),
         timezone: "America/Mexico_City",
       }
>>> $fechaNueva = App\User::first()->updated_at;

    => Illuminate\Support\Carbon @1589413041 {#3127
         date: 2020-05-13 18:37:21.0 America/Mexico_City (-05:00),
         timezone: "America/Mexico_City",
       }
>>> $fechaAntigua->diffInDays($fechaNueva);

    => 12
```

**Referencia**

- [API Carbon Difference](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-difference)